# What should I do about my answer?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I answered a question. Later, another user answered it more accurately and better. And in reality the other is the correct one. So should I delete/edit my answer or do nothing?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the answer in question?

Comment: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19371/is-it-possible-for-a-genin-to-become-a-jonin/19381#19381 this one

Comment: As Madara said in the answer below, there's really no need for you to do anything. Furthermore, the fact that another [answer is accepted](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), doesn't mean it is better than yours, just that the OP feels that one addresses his question better. [Votes](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) determine the acceptance of the answer by the community. Also, the other answer refers to a movie in the Naruto universe, whereas yours doesn't. So both answers can technically be correct, if you disregard the movie as not being canon.

Comment: Oh :) Thanks senpai :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do nothing. Stack Exchange sites are designed to have questions with multiple answers, with the best getting voted to the top.

Don't worry about it.

Comment: umm, did you delete that [answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/214/why-isnt-tobi-blind-yet/21001?noredirect=1#comment28407_21001)? Can't access chat right now.

Comment: Nope. It was deleted by owner.